# Facetime is answered on remote / Camera turned on while no one is at the computer - and it's locked

Tags: macos, security, facetime, malware, webcam

**Update**: I've been able to confirm that Facetime is the trigger

I've come home to unlock my OSX Monterey (build 21G72?), only to notice Facetime is running with the camera on. This has now happened multiple times across multiple days. I explicitly killed Facetime after the first event. I am on the only person who has physical access to the machine.

Has anyone seen something like this?  Based on the latest logs, this appears to be just a crappy bug.

Unfortunately the console logs are sparse and not able to reproduce. Only two things stand out:

- Timestamps that correlate to incoming Facetime calls (which also went, and were answered on, my mobile.)
- The diagnostics agent...

[image]

```
com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.AddressBook.accounts.summary
com.apple.message.summarize: YES
com.apple.message.carddav_accounts: 1
com.apple.message.disabled_accounts: 0
com.apple.message.enabled_accounts: 2
com.apple.message.ldap_accounts: 0
com.apple.message.exchange_accounts: 0
com.apple.message.total_accounts: 3
SenderMachUUID: <redacted>
```

[image: Evidence from call logs]